# module 'discord' has no attribute 'Channel'

Tags: python

I'm currently programming a Discord bot that allows you to play poker with other people. Unfortunately the error comes: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Channel'.
Can anyone help me further? Many Thanks!
best regards

Code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

from typing import Dict, List

import discord

from game import Game, GAME_OPTIONS, GameState


POKER_BOT_TOKEN = "My_Token"

client = discord.Client()

games: Dict[discord.Channel, Game] = {}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback fully explains the issue. `Channel` is not a known discord model.

If  your bot will run in text channels you can use `discord.TextChannel` instead.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-models

Comment: Thank you! I hope you can solve my next (and last) problem, too. :)

Comment: Sure. To send a message in the same channel in which the command was invoked, you need to use `await message.channel.send("message_text_goes_here")`. If that solved the problem, please remember to remove your post below since it's not an answer and may be confusing to anyone with your same issue :)